# Azure AzApi provider in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to use Azure AzApi provider to update the Azure key vault key rotation policy.
Both "Azure AzApi provider" and Key Rotation Policy are very new features, released last week.

I don't get any error but it is not updating the attributes.

Code is very simple:

- read existing Key vault
- create a key using "azurerm_key_vault_key" resource
- Add Key rotation policy config using "azapi_update_resource" resource

My Code:

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "this" {
  name                = "kv33eerr"
  resource_group_name = "test"
}

resource "time_offset" "expiration_days" {
  offset_days = 364
}

resource  "azurerm_key_vault_key" "generated" {
  name            = "testkey01"
  key_vault_id    = data.azurerm_key_vault.this.id
  key_type        = "RSA"
  key_size        = 2048
  expiration_date = time_offset.expiration_days.rfc3339

  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey",
  ]
}

resource "azapi_update_resource" "rotaion" {
  type      = "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2021-10-01"
  parent_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.this.id
  name      = azurerm_key_vault_key.generated.name
  
  body = jsonencode(
    {
      properties = {
        lifetimeactions = [
          {
            action           = "rotate"
            timeaftercreate  = "p545d"
            timebeforeexpiry = null
          },
          {
            action           = "notify"
            timeaftercreate  = null
            timebeforeexpiry = "p20d"
          }
        ],
        expiresin        = "p2y"
      }

    }
  )

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_key.generated
  ]
}
```

---

Terraform Apply:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # azapi_update_resource.rotaion will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azapi_update_resource" "rotaion" {
      ~ body                    = jsonencode(
          ~ {
              ~ properties = {
                  + expiresin       = "p2y"
                  + lifetimeactions = [
                      + {
                          + action           = "rotate"
                          + timeaftercreate  = "p545d"
                          + timebeforeexpiry = null
                        },
                      + {
                          + action           = "notify"
                          + timeaftercreate  = null
                          + timebeforeexpiry = "p30d"
                        },
                    ]
                }
            }
        )
        id                      = "/subscriptions/32055728-56f6-46dd-8fd1-3f50d4ae69a5/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/kv33eerr/keys/testkey01"
        name                    = "testkey01"
      ~ output                  = jsonencode({}) -> (known after apply)
        # (5 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

azapi_update_resource.rotaion: Modifying... [id=/subscriptions/32055728-56f6-46dd-8fd1-3f50d4ae69a5/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/kv33eerr/keys/testkey01]
azapi_update_resource.rotaion: Modifications complete after 3s [id=/subscriptions/3205xxxx-56f6-46dd-8fd1-3f50d4ae69a5/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/kv33eerr/keys/testkey01]

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

---

key rotation policy:

```
az keyvault key rotation-policy show -n testkey01 --vault-name kv33eerr
{
  "createdOn": null,
  "expiresIn": null,
  "id": null,
  "lifetimeActions": [
    {
      "action": "Notify",
      "timeAfterCreate": null,
      "timeBeforeExpiry": "P30D"
    }
  ],
  "updatedOn": null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload is not accurate, strongly recommended to install AzApi VSCode Extension, it provides a rich authoring experience to help you use the AzApi provider: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=azapi-vscode.azapi

```
resource "azapi_update_resource" "test" {
  type      = "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2021-11-01-preview"
  name      = azurerm_key_vault_key.generated.name
  parent_id = azurerm_key_vault_key.generated.key_vault_id

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      rotationPolicy = {
        lifetimeActions = [
          {
            action = {
              type = "Rotate"
            }
            trigger = {
              timeAfterCreate  = "P20D"
              timeBeforeExpiry = null
            }
          },
          {
            action = {
              type = "Notify"
            }
            trigger = {
              timeAfterCreate  = null
              timeBeforeExpiry = "P20D"
            }
          }
        ],
        attributes = {
          expiryTime = "P2Y"
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/2021-11-01-preview/vaults/keys?tabs=json